# Underscore template does not load the Model.id, on printing the <% console.log(Model.id) %> it comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

the expense.id prints as undefined in the log

My Underscore template

```
<% _.each(expenses, function(expense) { %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= expense.get('name') %></td>
    <td><%= expense.get('amount') %></td>
    <td><%= expense.get('category') %></td>
    <td><% console.log(expense.id) %></td>
  </tr>
<% }); %>
```

My Backbone View

```
var ExpenseList = Backbone.View.extend({    
    el: '.page',
    render : function(){
        var expenses = new Expenses();
        var that = this;
        expenses.fetch({
          success : function(expenses){
            var template = _.template($('#expense-list-template').html(),
                                      {expenses: expenses.models});     
            that.$el.html(template);    
          }
        });         
    }
});
```

Server Response

```
[
  {
    "_id": "53c25827555953000091ab71",
    "name": "Shell",
    "amount": "$1000",
    "category": "Internet"
  },

  {
    "_id": "53c2bfee4bf93700006fb714",
    "name": "FC",
    "amount": "$432",
    "category": "Game"
  }
]
```

Comment: I've updated the server response and it does contain the id

Comment: @user3758631, It contains `_id`, which is different than `id`.

Comment: @fbynite  -tried both expense._id and expense['_id'] still the value is returned undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is sending back `_id` attributes, not `id` attributes.

The easiest option would be to set [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) on your model:

```
var Expense = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id',
    //...
});
var Expenses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Expense,
    //...
});
```

That will give you `expense.get('_id')` and `expense.id` as the same thing and the models will send `_id` back to the server.

You could also add a [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method to your model to rename the attribute but that would cause problems when you tried to send data back to the server.